# Do questions require specific problems, or are general reviews on-topic?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I have read; the [Tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), [What not to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I am unsure whether questions should specify specific problems, or if I should specify parts of the code where improvement is desired.

I have seen questions which describe the purpose of the code joined by the code. The question don't bring up any specific problems with the code; like redundancy, performance, etc.

Are general questions acceptable? Or should I find a specific part of my code I would like to improve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. "[Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" means all questions are open to general reviews, even if you mention a specific aspect you want reviewed. Questions don't need to specify specific problems or parts of the code where improvement is desired.

If you think your code is as good as you can make it, please do post the code for review and learn from other users' suggestions.